# Attaching individual css and javascript file with partial view of angular route

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have tried many different approach but nothing is working as I expected. I've few css and javascript files, that I want to load along with partial associated to my Angular route. Is there any way I can do this? There were some solution around on the web, but nothing seems to work as per their instruction.

Comment: Post some code that you have tried??

Comment: I went through this [1] but it was giving me error for injectedStylesheets.

[1] - https://github.com/Yappli/angular-css-injector/blob/main/angular-css-injector.js